# Using stateHelper with ui-router Can't resolve 'app.user.home' from state '' where user is a child abstract state of abstract state app

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

After trying to use the stateHelper to reorganize my app's menu layout I'm getting an error;

```
Error: Could not resolve 'app.user.home' from state ''
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:49177)
    at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:49110)
    at app.js:220
```

This happens when my app loads and `$state.go('app.user.home')` runs on app.js:220

My situation is that admin users are shown a "hamburger stack" icon that opens a side menu with certain views only admins can navigate to.

When a non-admin enters the same view they are shown a "home" icon instead that links to the home view.

Both admins and non-admins have the home view which has `ui-sref` links to additional views they can both navigate to.

When the "hamburger icon" is shown for an admin the `ui-sref` to the home view is moved to the side menu.

This is my `stateHelperProvider` code;

```
.config(function(stateHelperProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

  stateHelperProvider

  .state({
    name: 'app',
    url: '/',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'MenuCtrl',
  })
  .state({
    name: 'app.user',
    url: '/user',
    abstract: true,
    children:[
      {
        name: 'app.user.home',
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/landing.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      },
      {
        name: 'app.user.board',
        url: '/board',
        templateUrl: 'templates/pta-board.html',
        controller: 'BoardCtrl'
      },
      {
        name: 'app.user.events',
        url: 'events',
        templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
      },
      {
        name: 'app.user.chatrooms',
        url: '/chat-rooms',
        templateUrl: 'templates/chat-rooms.html',
        controller: 'RoomsCtrl',
        children:[
          {
            name: 'app.user.chatrooms.chatroom',
            url: '/room',
            templateUrl: 'templates/chat-room.html',
            params:{
              roomId: null,
              chatters: null
            },
            controller: 'ChatCtrl'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'app.user.profile',
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'templates/user-profile.html',
        params:{
          isNewUser: null
        },
        controller: 'UserCtrl'
      },
      { name: 'app.user.admin',
        url: 'admin',
        abstract: true,
        children:[
          {
            name: 'app.user.admin.calendar',
            url: '/calendar',
            params:{
              selectedEvent: null,
              calendarTitle: 'Volunteer',
              isVolunteerSignup: true
            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/rcalendar.html',
            controller: 'CalendarCtrl'
          },
          {
            name: 'app.user.admin.volunteers',
            url: '/volunteers',
            params:{
              thisHoursVolunteers: null,
              thisEvent: null
            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/admin-interact.html',
            controller: 'VolunteerCtrl'
          },
          {
            name: 'app.user.admin.roles',
            url: '/roles',
            templateUrl: 'templates/roles.html',
            controller: 'RoleCtrl'
          },
          {
            name: 'app.user.admin.settings',
            url: '/settings',
            templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  })

  .state({
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller : 'LoginCtrl'
  })

  .state({
    name: 'signup',
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
    controller : 'SignupCtrl'
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
});
```

My side menu, menu.html,  template;

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar ng-class="{'has-subject': subject}" 
                 class="white-font bar-header bar-positive">
      <!-- <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button> -->
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left" >
        <button ng-if="$root.isAdmin" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
        <button ng-if="!$root.isAdmin" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-home" ui-sref="app.user.home">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view> <!-- ionic's equivalent to ui-view -->    
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu class="side-menu" width="140" side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="white-font bar-header bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Admin Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close>
          <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ui-sref="app.user.admin.calendar({ calendarTitle: 'Calendar', isVolunteerSignup: false })">Calendar</a>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close>
          <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ui-sref="app.user.admin.roles">Roles</a>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close>
          <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ui-sref="app.user.home">Main Menu</a>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close>
          <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ui-sref="app.user.admin.settings">School Settings</a>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

And then my home view;

```
<ion-view class="landing" title="{{school.name}}">
  <div ng-if="school.logo" class="tall bar bar-header">
    <img class="school-logo" ng-src="{{school.logo}}" >
  </div>
  <ion-content ng-class="{'has-tall-header': school.logo}">
    <ion-list class="nav-buttons">
      <ion-item>
        <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ui-sref="app.user.board">
          PTA Board
          <i class="icon ion-board"></i>
        </a>
      </ion-item>        
      <ion-item>
        <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ui-sref="app.user.events">
          Events
          <i class="icon ion-calendar"></i>
        </a>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ui-sref="app.user.rooms">
          Chat
          <i class="icon ion-chatboxes"></i>
        </a>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ui-sref="app.user.profile">
          Profile
          <i class="icon ion-android-user-menu"></i>
        </a>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <a class="button button-block button-clear button-dark" ng-click="logout()">
          Logout
          <i class="icon ion-log-out"></i>
        </a>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because the state I was asking for did not get registered. I was able to fix the error by updating the state name properties in my stateHelper code so that they did not contain the dot notation for their parent, as shown here.

```
.config(function(stateHelperProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

  stateHelperProvider

  .state({
    name: 'app',
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'MenuCtrl',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'user',
        url: '/user',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>',
        children:[
          {
            name: 'home', 
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'templates/landing.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          },
          {
            name: 'board',
            url: '/board',
            templateUrl: 'templates/pta-board.html',
            controller: 'BoardCtrl' 
          },
          {
            name: 'events',
            url: '/events',
            templateUrl: 'templates/events.html',
            controller: 'EventsCtrl'
          },
          {
            name: 'chatrooms',
            url: '/chat-rooms',
            templateUrl: 'templates/chat-rooms.html',
            controller: 'RoomsCtrl',
            children:[
              {
                name: 'room',
                url: '/room',
                params:{
                  roomId: null,
                  chatters: null
                },
                 templateUrl: 'templates/chat-room.html',
                 controller: 'ChatCtrl'
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            name: 'profile',
            url: '/profile',
            params:{
              isNewUser: null
            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/user-profile.html',
            controller: 'UserCtrl'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: 'admin',
        url: '/admin',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>',
        children:[
          {
            name: 'calendar',
            url: '/calendar',
            params:{
              selectedEvent: null,
              calendarTitle: 'Volunteer',
              isVolunteerSignup: true
            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/rcalendar.html',
            controller: 'CalendarCtrl'
          },
          {
            name: 'volunteers',
            url: '/volunteers',
            params:{
              thisHoursVolunteers: null,
              thisEvent: null
            },
            templateUrl: 'templates/admin-interact.html',
            controller: 'VolunteerCtrl'
          },
          {
            name: 'roles',
            url: '/roles',
            templateUrl: 'templates/roles.html',
            controller: 'RoleCtrl'
          },
          {
            name: 'settings',
            url: '/settings',
            templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  })
  .state({
    name: 'login', 
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller : 'LoginCtrl' 
  })
  .state({
    name: 'signup',
    url: '/signup',
    templateUrl: 'templates/signup.html',
    controller : 'SignupCtrl' 
  });
```

I'm still not able to navigate to the `board`, `events`, `chatrooms` or `profile` states but I no longer get any errors. And `admin` child and all other states, including `home` oddly enough, work as expected.